# Show @NotNull message in p:tooltip

Tags: jsf, bean-validation, message

I was wondering if one could access the validation error message assigned via Bean validation through the UIInput's binding.

For example, i have the following property:

```
@NotNull(message = "{username_required}")
private String username;
```

When I print the error using h:message, i get the appropriate message printed out, so I know that Bean Validation works correctly. I would like to print out the message without h:message tag, supplying the value directly to a tooltip, like this:

```
 <p:tooltip for="usernameErrorImage" rendered="#{!usernameInputBinding.valid}" 
     value="#{!usernameInputBinding.requiredMessage}"/>
```

The 'rendered' attribute works as expected, however the value of the tooltip is 'true', which is not my message. I have also tried 'convertedMessage' and 'requiredMessage', but both of them also return the string 'true'. Putting the h:message inside of the tooltip tag prints out the message, however I would like to know if I can access the validation message directly through the binding.

Comment: You put a boolean negation condition in there as in `#{!foo}` and you're wondering why it returns `true`? Didn't it occur to you that you've to remove the `!` in order to not make it a boolean negation? In any case, I'm not sure what you're asking but it sounds like as if you're expecting that bean valiation messages are available via `requiredMessage` attribute. This is not true. It will only return the `requiredMessage` attribute which you've explicitly set yourself as in `<h:inputXxx requiredMessage="Please enter this field">` which only works in combination with `required="true"`.

Comment: @BalusC Ty for response Balus. I'm not sure how that exclamation mark slipped in, it was kind of late. Yes, I'd like to access bean validation message somehow. H:Message must read it from somewhere, and I was hoping that the value might be accessible via binding. Is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you've a `ValidationMessages.properties` with among others the `username_required` entry, just use `<f:loadBundle>` the usual way to load it as a resource bundle in JSF view.

```
<f:loadBundle basename="ValidationMessages" var="validationMessages" />
...
<p:tooltip ... value="#{validationMessages['username_required']}"/>
```

Grabbing the component's `requiredMessage` attribute as in your initial attempt will definitely not work as it only returns the manually definied `requiredMessage` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest the message inside the tooltip.
This worked for me in Primefaces 4.

bean:

```
@NotNull(message = "{username_required}")
private String username;
```

xhtml:

```
<p:tooltip for="usernameErrorImage">
    <p:message for="usernameErrorImage" />
</p:tooltip>
```